# Unable to replace/delete \xa0 from a string in Python (parsing from Excel)

Tags: python

```
    from collections import Counter
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    nomefile = 'SerieA18_19.xlsx'

    wb = load_workbook(nomefile)
    ws = wb.worksheets
    sheet = wb.active
    max_row = sheet.max_row

    results = []
    for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
      cell_obj = sheet.cell(i, 1).value
      cell_obj.strip()
      cell_obj.replace('\\xa0', ' ')
      if cell_obj[2:3] == '-':
         results.append(cell_obj)
      if cell_obj[3:4] == '-' and cell_obj[:1] != '(':
         results.append(cell_obj)


    results_counter = Counter()
    for response in results:
       results_counter.update(response.split(','))

    print(results_counter)
```

OUTPUT is as follows :
        Counter({'1\xa0-\xa01': 44, '2\xa0-\xa01': 39, '1\xa0-\xa00': 35, '0\xa0-\xa00': 34, '2\xa0-  \xa00': 28, '0\xa0-\xa01':

I am not able to delete/replace these '\xa0' that are probably coming from the Excel file

Comment: The strange issue is that if I  print(results[0]) the output is correct  '1-1'

Answer (score 1):

String in python is immutable. You need to assign the value to a variable.
Replace

```
cell_obj.strip()
cell_obj.replace('\\xa0', ' ')
```

with

```
  cell_obj = cell_obj.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also chr(160).
When .encode('utf-8'), it will encode the unicode to utf-8, that means every unicode could be represented by 1 to 4 bytes. For this case, \xa0 is represented by 2 bytes \xc2\xa0.

Read up on http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html.

Comment: You are right but doesn't work either

Comment: I've just tried but nothing changes in the output

Comment: Try:  cell_obj = cell_obj.strip().replace(r"\xa0", ' ') @AlPan

Comment: It doesn't change

Comment: Check the edited answer @AlPan

Comment: ichanged the above row in          cell_obj = cell_obj.strip().encode('utf-8')  but Counter in Output is empty now

Comment: Yea, Needs to encode it to utf-8. So did my answer work? It also changes it to utf-8. Did you try this?   cell_obj = cell_obj.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ')

Comment: not really, output now is   ->      Counter()

Comment: GREEEEAAAAT  !!! Now it is perfect   thnks

Comment: ok cool. I had actually updated to this answer like 12 mins ago. I also you didn't see my updated answer. Thats why asked you to again to check. Happy that it worked. Kindly accept my answer

Comment: i did it but my reputation is still too low

Comment: Try now. Either upvote or accept answer should work. If it didn't ignore. Happy that the problem is solved.